# Error converting between dateformats in c#

Tags: c#, date-format, cultureinfo, datetime-parsing

I have the following data in my date field of my `GridView`: `2016-01-24T00:00:00`
Before updating that field, I want to store that value in "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

To do that I'm doing the following:

```
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
string formattedHolDate = DateTime.ParseExact(holDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", culture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

However, when running the code, I have the following error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

What is the right way to handle it?

Comment: why are you telling c# to expect `dd/mm/yyyy` formatted string, then pass in `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`? and then why are you expecting C# to read your mind and figure out what you REALLY wanted?

Comment: I know it was not right way to do it, but format should I use in that case?

Comment: tell c# what format your input string **IS**. formatting for output comes AFTER you've successfully parsed that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I am reading your question.

> 2016-01-24T00:00:00 (what you have)
>
> "dd/MM/yyyy" (what you want)

```
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
var myDate = DateTime.Parse(holDate);
string myFormattedDateString = myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

You had some stuff turned around.

- `Parse` = converting from string to a date (or other object depending on the implementation)
- `ToString` - converting from object to a string representation

**Edit**

As `2016-01-24T00:00:00` is actually an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) representation of a DateTime you do not need `ParseExact`, just `Parse` will do.

Comment: I tried your example and I got an error: `DateTime pattern 'm' appears more than once with different values`

Comment: I got it. Thx. I should have used `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`